# MySQL acting as bottleneck with multiple INSERT (NodeJS)

Tags: mysql, node.js, csv

I am trying to process a huge CSV file (650 million rows) row by row using NodeJS and then inserting the rows in a MySQL database. I keep in memory sets of 5000 rows and then I perform a multiple INSERT on the database (INSERT INTO tableName (field1,field2) VALUES ('a','a'),('b','b')...)

When launching the script it works pretty well (5000 rows are inserted each 1.5 seconds approximately). However, when 6 million rows have been processed and inserted, the INSERTs start to take about 8-9 seconds, slowing down the process.

What could be happening? Is the MySQL server acting as bottleneck? Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: This is the CREATE TABLE:

```
sips2consumo_20200826 | CREATE TABLE `sips2consumo_20200826` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `field1` varchar(22) NOT NULL,
  `field2` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `field3` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `field4` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
  `field5` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field6` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field7` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field8` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field9` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field10` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field11` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field12` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field13` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field14` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field15` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field16` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field17` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field18` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field19` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field20` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field21` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field22` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field23` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field24` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `unique_consumption` (`field1`,`field2`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

Comment: Why don't you use load data infile instead of bulk insert? Do you commit after each 5k records?

Comment: @Shadow I need to do some manual checks for some columns to drop some rows, that is why I am not using LOAD DATA INFILE. I store the information of 5000 rows in NODEJS and then I perform a single INSERT query with the information of the 5000 rows.

Comment: Do you commit after each 5k record batch? Do you have indexes defined on the table in which you are inserting into?

Comment: I do not use transactions so I do not explicitly commit. Would it be a good idea to use transactions? No, I do not have any index on the table. Thanks for your replies

Comment: If you are using innodb and autocommit is on, then each statement would be a transaction itself. What about indexes? Do you have any declared on the table?

Comment: Yep, I am using innodb and autocommit is on. I have no index, it is a simple table with 15 fields and just one of them acting as primary key. No foreign keys, no indexes

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you are using mysql, most probably you are creating connections every time, you need to create connection once and insert data in batches as you are doing with 5000 rows a time and when completed close the connection,

Also it is good practice to keep your counter (last row inserted) persistent somewhere so in case of failure you don't start from 0th row, instead continue from the last inserted row before failure.

Comment: thanks for your reply. That is exactly how I am working: I do never close the connection until the end of the file processing and I have an auxiliary table where I store every 5000 lines the progress to resume the process if needed.

Comment: The problem is that, at a certain point, the MySQL server seems to be overloaded and batched inserts start to take 8 seconds instead of 1-2 seconds...

Comment: Can you confirm if your batches are executed synchronously or asynchronously? If asynchronously then try to sleep (say 1000 milliseconds) processing after some rows say 100,000 this will give mysql some time to clear in memory data

Comment: They are executed asynchronously. Good idea, I will try out and post the results tomorrow. Thank you!

Comment: It improved the performance at the beginning but the problem appeared again when 37 millions lines had been processed...

Comment: you have to do the maths, based on your app server (node code) and db server configuration, and find those 2 magical numbers, it will solve the issue

Comment: I am wondering if you have created indexes on MySql table (It will help a bit) also check this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-optimization.html#:~:text=You%20can%20use%20the%20following,separate%20single%2Drow%20INSERT%20statements.